# GWT Handling StatusCodeException

Tags: gwt

How to get exception from server side, if my service method throws new MyException("Some reason");
I would like to get MyException in onFailure method, but actually I got StatusCodeException. Can I get MyException in order to show error msg on UI :
Window.alert(exception.getMessage()); -> prints : "Some reason"

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("reportService.rpc")
public interface ReportService extends RemoteService {
    void saveReport(ReportDTO reportDTO) throws MyException;
}

 @Override
    public void saveReport(ReportDTO reportDTO) throws MyException {
        //Report report = ReportFunc.INST.apply(reportDTO);
        //reportRepository.save(report);
        throw new MyException("Some reason");
    }

 reportServiceAsync.saveReport(reportDTO, new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                        Window.alert("Successfully saved");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                        Window.alert(e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

class MyException extends RuntimeException implements Serializable{
  ....
}
```

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you get your message as a StatuscodeException? Which is the Statuscode? 500 or 404?

Comment: 500 exactly, it's means that error occurred on server side.

Comment: If you get a 500 you should have something in the server logs, but I'd bet it's not directly related to the thrown exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception should extend Exception, not RuntimeException.

Comment: I have done this, but still have the same StatusCodeException

Comment: I changed to extends Exception. It's a pity, but I have the same error 500 Internal Server Error StatusCodeException

Comment: I have changed to IOException and the same error occurred.

Comment: Maybe this exception is thrown for another reason? Can you make sure that it is thrown by this code line?

Comment: Oh my GOD, Andrei you are right, I am mistaken. Now it fixed, everything is ok. Thank you :)